# What image bit types are supported by Google Cloud AutoML Vision?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

The [AutoML documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare) has the supported file types, but not information on supported image bit types. Specifically, I know that 16 bit has spotty support among python image processing libraries. Can AutoML handle 16 bit?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AutoML Vision does support 16-bit images. I tried using 16-bit BMP files and it worked correctly; however, consider that there's a [limit](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare#preparing_your_images) of 30MB per image for training/offline prediction and 1.5MB per image for online prediction and 16-bit images are normally larger than 8-bit.

In addition, I tried [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop) with these images and it worked too.

**UPDATE**

I sent a request to the AutoML Vision team, to include this information in their documentation.